# Api keys in Rest Apis

Tags: node.js, rest, express, django-rest-framework

I have a test question that say : use header Authorization with api key to secure your endpoints
But what confused me is the endpoints have no login and registration mechanisms , how can I deal with api keys in this situation

Comment: By my experience, I have to have registration and login to some appliacation, which then tells me the API key. (Typically what came on my mind is Wakatime). If there is now registration, then the API key is assigned to you by any other manager of the application, isn't it?

Comment: I get confused when I first read it , maybe I can generate the key using the ip address  or something else

Comment: Is the service you are talking about public? Maybe we could help you better.

Comment: @Fide   It is public

Comment: So what service is it? So I can check it.

Comment: A simple api in express for an opportunity  test,  the api is managing products

Comment: the CRUD operations must be done with an api key with every call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247181/discussion-between-rusty-and-fide).